# VLC: Subtitle on a separate window

Tags: vlc

Could someone help me how I can display a movie subtitle on a different windows than movie is showing.
I need a narrow window beside the main vlc windows showing the subtitle, similar to YouTube's `Show Transcript` feature.

Can it be written as a Lua extension maybe? IF so, can somebody put me in a right track?

I attached a visual presentation:

[image]

YouTube:
[image]